# How to get MIME type of a text file without extension in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mime-types

How can I get MIME type of a text file with no extension in Node.js? I am using file-type package, but it does not detect file type of text files.
Thanks

Comment: Like what? do you want to somehow detect if a file is a js file, or a html file, or etc? If so, that's pretty tricky because its just plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

Without a helper package, you can't *easily* tell of which format is a certain text file. There just isn't a place where different file formats say who they are; you would have to use a bunch of regexes, one for each file format.

Comment: Technically speaking, libmagic can detect file types, but it only works for *binary* files and not plaintext like what OP is asking for.